# setTimeout runs immediately instead of waiting the delay value

Tags: javascript, time, timeout, alarm

I am absolutely puzzled. Why is this program not using the delay number I got which I named "result". It is supposed to subtract the current time by the future date a user posts. This would end up as an alarm. 
Just take a look, run the code.

```js
            // Set a future time you want the alert() function to go off
            var eta_ms = new Date(2017, 1, 26, 17, 06).getTime();
    
            document.write(Date.now() + "<br />");
            document.write(eta_ms + "<br />");
    
            var result = eta_ms - Date.now();
            document.write("The Delay: " + result + "<br />" );
            document.write(result + "<br />");
            document.write(typeof (result) + "<br />");
    
            setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, result);
```

Comment: are there any errors in  the developer tools console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JavaScript uses a 32-bit integer to store the delay value. That makes the maximum value you can use 2147483647.**

This means that the longest possible `setTimeout` or `setInterval` delay you can have is 2,147,483,647 milliseconds or 24.85513480324074 days.

Your value winds up being 2,677,448,064, or 31 days from now (`new Date(2017, 1, 26, 17, 06)` is February 26, 2017) and that is larger than the max value and so it breaks down and runs as soon as it can.

**If you really did intend for this to be a long-term timer and even if there were no max value for `setTimeout`, this would only work if the user kept your page open in their browser the entire time they were waiting for the alarm.**

The better solution for a long-term timer would be to store the time the alarm was supposed to go off (not the amount of time between now and then) in **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** and upon page load, get that value out and compare it to the current time.

Comment: @AhmedAhmed This should be the answer. Not telling you how to fix the code, but telling you **exactly** why you have the problem.

Comment: Helping reading your answer would be wise, I learnt something new about the max-values of setTimeout or setInterval. You are right and do not take me wrong please, just a question: Setting a future time in the next month in this example, is this very likely? Or in order words, exceeding max-values of setTimeout or setInterval.

Comment: @Blauharley Is it likely that a future time for an alarm would be a full month away? Sure, why not. You can make this work, but you just won't be able to use `setTimout` to do it. And, even if you could, it would only work if the user kept their browser open the entire time they were waiting.  The better solution for a long-term timer would be to store the alarm time in `localStorage` and upon page load, get that value out and compare it to the current time.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That is really interesting to know if I wanted an alarm to be over 24 days long.

Answer (score 5):

Just set Month 0 (second parameter of Date-constructor) then it should work, as expected.

And please take note that when you run this code after 23:35 (26.01.2017) *result* gets negative because you have to set *eta_ms* always in the future.

Hope this helps:

```
    var eta_ms = new Date(2017, 0, 26, 23, 35).getTime();
    document.write(Date.now() + "<br />");
    document.write(eta_ms + "<br />");

    var result = eta_ms - Date.now();
    document.write("The Delay: " + result + "<br />" );
    document.write(result + "<br />");
    document.write(typeof (result) + "<br />");

    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, result);
```

Better approach, in order to avoid setting month 0, could be to set the future time (*eta_ms*) in another way, so that someone just has to change this *minutesInFuture* variable in order to change *eta_ms*. In this fashion eta_ms is not restricted to January:

```
    var minutesInFuture = 5;

    var eta_ms = new Date().getTime();
    eta_ms = eta_ms + minutesInFuture * 1000 * 60;

    document.write(Date.now() + "<br />");
    document.write(eta_ms + "<br />");

    var result = eta_ms - Date.now();
    document.write("The Delay: " + result + "<br />" );
    document.write(result + "<br />");
    document.write(typeof (result) + "<br />");

    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, result);
```

(Month 0) As its states [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: For more info, double check which Date attributes are 0-based and which are 1-based: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: So, if the OP changes the line to: `var result = Date.now() - eta_ms;` and wants to use 2/1/2017 as `result`, will this answer help?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: The answer is no, but eta_ms should always be in the future.

Comment: So, I guess my point was that changing the month to 0 really isn't an answer. It's a manual adjustment to the data that the OP didn't ask for. What if the OP really did mean 2/26/2017?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: You are absolute right. It shoudl be as flexible as possible. hope my second part did a better job.

Comment: I don't see how your adjusted code solves the problem in any way. It just moves some of the values around. The exact same issue still persists if you wanted an alarm for a month from now.

Answer (score 0):

Because months are 0-based in Javascript.  So month #1 is February.  I believe this insane feature was borrowed from Java.

Comment: How is this the answer? What if the OP was trying to make an alarm that goes off on 2/26/17?